# Button's OnClick event doesn't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, click, web-controls

The following code is my ASP.NET page :

```
<MdsMenu:MenuItem Text="Button" Href="#">
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button 01" OnClick="Button_Click" />
   <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button 02" OnClick="Button_Click" />
</MdsMenu:MenuItem>
```

I don't know why Button_Click event doesn't fire !!!

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button senderButton = sender as Button;
   Label1.Text = senderButton.ID.ToString();
}
```

**MdsMenu:MenuItem** is my custom WebControl.
If I insert a Button control out of MdsMenu:MenuItem tag it works well but if I inserted it within MdsMenu:MenuItem tag it doesn't fire the concerned method.
What's wrong with my code ?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Menu.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;

namespace MenuServerControl
{
    [AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)]
    [AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)]
    [DefaultProperty("MenuItems")]
    [ParseChildren(true, "MenuItems")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:Menu runat=\"server\"> </{0}:Menu>")]
    public class Menu : WebControl
    {
        #region Fields

        private List<MenuItem> _MenuItems;
        string _Direction
        {
            get
            {
                string direction = "";
                switch (this.Direction)
                {
                    case Directions.LeftToRight:
                        direction = "direction:ltr;";
                        break;
                    case Directions.RightToLeft:
                        direction = "direction:rtl;";
                        break;
                    default:
                        direction = "direction:rtl;";
                        break;
                }
                return direction;
            }
        }
        string _AnimationDelay
        {
            get
            {
                if (AnimationDelay == null)
                    AnimationDelay = 1000;
                return AnimationDelay.ToString().ToLower();
            }
        }
        string _AnimationType
        {
            get
            {
                switch (this.AnimationType)
                {
                    case AnimationType.Opacity_Height:
                        return "animation:{opacity:'show',height:'show'}";
                    case AnimationType.Opacity_Width:
                        return "animation:{opacity:'show',width:'show'}";
                    case AnimationType.Opacity:
                        return "animation:{opacity:'show'}";
                    case AnimationType.Height:
                        return "animation:{height:'show'}";
                    case AnimationType.Width:
                        return "animation:{width:'show'}";
                    case AnimationType.Height_Toggle:
                        return "animation: {height: 'toggle'}";
                    case AnimationType.Width_Toggle:
                        return "animation: {width: 'toggle'}";
                    default:
                        return "animation:{opacity:'show',height:'show'}";
                }
            }
        }
        string _AnimationSpeed
        {
            get
            {
                switch (this.AnimationSpeed)
                {
                    case AnimationSpeed.Fast:
                        return "speed:'fast'";
                    case AnimationSpeed.Normal:
                        return "speed:'normal'";
                    case AnimationSpeed.Slow:
                        return "speed:'slow'";
                    default:
                        return "speed:'fast'";
                }
            }
        }
        string FloatStyle
        {
            get
            {
                if (Direction == Directions.RightToLeft)
                    return "float:right;";
                else return "";
            }
        }
        string _Main_ul_CssClass = "";

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public string Main_ul_CssClass
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Main_ul_CssClass)) return "";
                _Main_ul_CssClass = "class=" + _Main_ul_CssClass;
                return _Main_ul_CssClass;
            }

            set
            {
                _Main_ul_CssClass = value.Trim();
            }
        }

        public Directions Direction { get; set; }

        public int? AnimationDelay { get; set; }

        public AnimationType AnimationType { get; set; }

        public AnimationSpeed AnimationSpeed { get; set; }

        public bool DropShadow { get; set; }

        public bool AutoArrows { get; set; }

        [Category("Behavior")]
        [Description("The menu collection")]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
        public List<MenuItem> MenuItems
        {
            get
            {
                if (_MenuItems == null)
                    _MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
                return _MenuItems;
            }
        }

        public VerOrHor VerticalOrHorizontal { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public Menu()
        {
            DropShadow = true;
            AutoArrows = true;
        }

        public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.Write("<div id=\"" + this.ID + "\" style=\"" + _Direction + " " + FloatStyle + "\">");
        }

        public override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.Write("</div>");
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);

            #region Adding Script & link Tags

            HtmlGenericControl jquery = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
            jquery.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
            jquery.Attributes.Add("src", Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(MenuServerControl.Menu), "MenuServerControl.JavaScriptFiles.jquery_1_4_3.js"));
            jquery.EnableViewState = false;
            Page.Header.Controls.Add(jquery);

            HtmlGenericControl hoverIntent = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
            hoverIntent.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
            hoverIntent.Attributes.Add("src", Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(Menu), "MenuServerControl.JavaScriptFiles.hoverIntent.js"));
            hoverIntent.EnableViewState = false;
            Page.Header.Controls.Add(hoverIntent);

            HtmlGenericControl jquery_bgiframe_min = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
            jquery_bgiframe_min.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
            jquery_bgiframe_min.Attributes.Add("src", Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(Menu), "MenuServerControl.JavaScriptFiles.jquery_bgiframe_min.js"));
            jquery_bgiframe_min.EnableViewState = false;
            Page.Header.Controls.Add(jquery_bgiframe_min);

            HtmlGenericControl superfish = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
            superfish.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
            superfish.Attributes.Add("src", Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(Menu), "MenuServerControl.JavaScriptFiles.superfish.js"));
            superfish.EnableViewState = false;
            Page.Header.Controls.Add(superfish);

            HtmlGenericControl supersubs = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
            supersubs.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
            supersubs.Attributes.Add("src", Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(Menu), "MenuServerControl.JavaScriptFiles.supersubs.js"));
            supersubs.EnableViewState = false;
            Page.Header.Controls.Add(supersubs);

            if (Direction == Directions.LeftToRight)
            {
                HtmlGenericControl csslink = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
                csslink.Attributes.Add("href", Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl
                    (typeof(Menu), "MenuServerControl.CSS.superfish.css"));
                csslink.ID = "NavigationMenu";
                csslink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
                csslink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
                csslink.EnableViewState = false;
                Page.Header.Controls.Add(csslink);
            }
            else
            {
                HtmlGenericControl csslink = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
                csslink.Attributes.Add("href", Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl
                    (typeof(Menu), "MenuServerControl.CSS.RightToLeft superfish.css"));
                csslink.ID = "NavigationMenu";
                csslink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
                csslink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
                csslink.EnableViewState = false;
                Page.Header.Controls.Add(csslink);
            }

            if (this.VerticalOrHorizontal == VerOrHor.Vertical && this.Direction == Directions.RightToLeft)
            {
                HtmlGenericControl csslink01 = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
                csslink01.Attributes.Add("href", Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl
                    (typeof(Menu), "MenuServerControl.CSS.RightToLeft superfish-vertical.css"));
                csslink01.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
                csslink01.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
                csslink01.EnableViewState = false;
                Page.Header.Controls.Add(csslink01);
            }
            else if (this.VerticalOrHorizontal == VerOrHor.Vertical)
            {
                HtmlGenericControl csslink01 = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
                csslink01.Attributes.Add("href", Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl
                    (typeof(Menu), "MenuServerControl.CSS.superfish-vertical.css"));
                csslink01.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
                csslink01.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
                csslink01.EnableViewState = false;
                Page.Header.Controls.Add(csslink01);
            }

            #endregion
        }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            output.Write(CreateMenuHtmlTags());
        }

        StringBuilder CreateMenuHtmlTags()
        {
            if (this._MenuItems == null)
                throw new Exception("تگ های مربوط به منو را کامل کنید");

            StringBuilder Html = new StringBuilder("");

            #region Add <Script>

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Main_ul_CssClass))
                Html.Append("<script>$(document).ready(function() { $(\"ul.sf-menu\").superfish({pathLevels:    1,");
            else
                Html.Append("<script>$(document).ready(function() { $(\"ul." + Main_ul_CssClass + "\").superfish({ pathLevels:    1,");

            Html.Append("delay:" + _AnimationDelay + ",");
            Html.Append(_AnimationType + ",");
            Html.Append(_AnimationSpeed + ",");
            Html.Append("dropShadows:  " + DropShadow.ToString().ToLower() + ",");
            Html.Append(@"autoArrows:  " + AutoArrows.ToString().ToLower() + "});});</script>");

            #endregion

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Main_ul_CssClass) && VerticalOrHorizontal == VerOrHor.Vertical)
                Html.Append("<ul class=\"sf-menu sf-vertical sf-js-enabled sf-shadow\" id='sample-menu-1'>");
            else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Main_ul_CssClass))
                Html.Append("<ul class=\"sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow\" id='sample-menu-1'>");
            else
                Html.Append("<ul class=\"" + Main_ul_CssClass + "\" id='sample-menu-1'>");

            foreach (MenuItem item in _MenuItems)
            {
                if (item == null) continue;
                if (item.SubMenuItems != null && item.SubMenuItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    Html.Append("<li" + item.li_CssClass + ">");
                    Html.Append("<a href=\"" + item.Href + "\">" + item.Text.Trim() + "</a>");
                    ParseSubMenuItems(ref Html, item);
                    Html.Append("</li>");
                }
                else if (item.SubMenuItems != null)
                    Html.Append("<li" + item.li_CssClass + "><a href=\"" + item.Href + "\">" + item.Text.Trim() + "</a></li>");
            }
            Html.Append("</ul>");

            return Html;
        }

        void ParseSubMenuItems(ref StringBuilder Html, MenuItem menuItems)
        {
            if (menuItems == null) return;

            Html.Append("<ul " + menuItems.ul_CssClass + " style=\"display: none; visibility: hidden;\">");

            foreach (var item in menuItems.SubMenuItems)
            {
                if (item == null) continue;

                MenuItem Sub_MenuItem = item as MenuItem;
                WebControl webControl = item as WebControl;

                if (Sub_MenuItem != null)
                {
                    if (Sub_MenuItem.SubMenuItems != null && Sub_MenuItem.SubMenuItems.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Html.Append("<li" + Sub_MenuItem.li_CssClass + ">");
                        Html.Append("<a href=\"" + Sub_MenuItem.Href + "\">" + Sub_MenuItem.Text.Trim() + "</a>");
                        ParseSubMenuItems(ref Html, Sub_MenuItem);
                        Html.Append("</li>");
                    }
                    else if (Sub_MenuItem.SubMenuItems != null)
                        Html.Append("<li" + Sub_MenuItem.li_CssClass + "><a href=\"" + Sub_MenuItem.Href + "\">" + Sub_MenuItem.Text.Trim() + "</a></li>");
                }
                else if (webControl != null)
                {
                    Html.Append("<li>");
                    webControl.EnableViewState = true;
                    this.Controls.Add(webControl);
                    webControl.EnableViewState = true;

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("<div>");
                    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
                    {
                        using (HtmlTextWriter textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                        {
                            webControl.RenderControl(textWriter);
                        }
                    }

                    sb.Append("</div>");

                    Html.Append(sb.ToString());
                    Html.Append("</li>");
                }
            }
            Html.Append("</ul>");
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

MenuItem.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;

namespace MenuServerControl
{
    [DefaultProperty("SubMenuItems")]
    [ParseChildren(true, "SubMenuItems")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public class MenuItem : INamingContainer
    {
        #region Fields

        ArrayList _SubMenuItems;
        string text = "";
        string href = "#";
        string _ul_CssClass = "";
        string _li_CssClass = "";

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        [Description("متن منو آیتم")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return text;
            }

            set
            {
                text = value;
            }
        }

        [DefaultValue("#")]
        [Description("<a /> href attribute")]
        [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
        public string Href
        {
            get
            {
                return href;
            }

            set
            {
                href = value;
            }
        }

        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Description("<ul /> css class")]
        [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
        public string ul_CssClass
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ul_CssClass)) return "";
                _ul_CssClass = " class=\"" + _ul_CssClass + "\"";
                return _ul_CssClass;
            }
            set { this._ul_CssClass = value.Trim(); }
        }

        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Description("<li /> css class")]
        [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
        public string li_CssClass
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_li_CssClass)) return "";
                _li_CssClass = " class=\"" + _li_CssClass + "\"";
                return _li_CssClass;
            }
            set { this._li_CssClass = value.Trim(); }
        }

        [Category("Behavior")]
        [Description("The MenuItems collection")]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
        public ArrayList SubMenuItems
        {
            get
            {
                if (_SubMenuItems == null)
                    _SubMenuItems = new ArrayList();
                return _SubMenuItems;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

You can download the project from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?zyji174v2d27600).

Comment: Did you put the Button_Click method on the MdsMenu class or on the containing page?

Comment: I put it on the containing page, because the user that is used my `MdsMenu:MenuItem` webcontrol must create it.

Comment: Please post code of MdsMenu maybe something there is causing this behavior.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or just a text editor, like Notepad?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: I've edited the post with my codes.

Comment: You're using `webControl.RenderControl(textWriter)` and this is probably "breaking" the OnClick of the buttons. To support such things you'll have to totally change your logic and instead of outputting pure HTML, add child controls to the Menu class - going to be lots of work. One work around that does not require lots of work is using JavaScript - if you're interested let me know and I'll demonstrate there's not enough room in the comment.

Comment: Thanks Shadow Wizard. I'm interested about it, please post it.

Comment: @Mohammad - see my answer, hope that's what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: have hidden button with the desired OnClick **outside** of the control, in the .aspx page itself e.g.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click" style="display: none;"  />
```

Step #2: have OnClientClick in the button inside the control, like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="SomeIdHere" runat="server" Text="Button 01" OnClientClick="return MakeRealClick('Button1');" />
```

Make sure to put the ID of the "real" button as the argument for "MakeRealClick" function.

Step #3: have this JavaScript code in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MakeRealClick(sButtonID) {
        var arrInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
            var oCurInput = arrInputs[i];
            if (oCurInput.type == "submit" && (oCurInput.id == sButtonID || EndsWith(oCurInput.id, "_" + sButtonID)))
                oCurInput.click();
        }
        return false;
    }

    function EndsWith(s1, s2) {
        return (s1.length >= s2.length) && (s1.substr(s1.length - s2.length, s2.length) == s2);
    }
</script>
```

This will cause that when clicked, the button inside the menu will search for other button that is outside the menu thus still has "real" OnClick, and auto click it so the final result is the same as if you clicked the hidden button.

Pretty sure there's better way, but like I said: quick fix with minimal change in code.

Comment: I resolve my problem with another way, but your guide was helpful. Thanks.